# How can I return two values but only show one in a textbox and hide the other in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to display only the quote in the quote textbox but I also want to display
the quotee name in the quotee textbox the problem is I can only return one value if I return both values they kinda go together in the quote textbox

```cs
public static string DisplayQuote() 
{
    Dictionary<string, string> quotes = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    quotes.Add("Dr. Seuss",
        "\"You’re off to great places, today is your day. Your mountain is waiting, so get onyour way.\"");
    quotes.Add("A.A. Milne",
        "\"You’re braver than you believe, and stronger than you seem, and smarter than you think.\"");
    quotes.Add("Willie Nelson", "\"Once you replace negative thoughts with positive ones, you’ll start having positive results.\"");
    quotes.Add("Les Brown", 
        "\"In every day, there are 1,440 minutes. That means we have 1,440 daily opportunities to make a positive impact.\"");
    quotes.Add("Dr Seuss",
        "\"When you are enthusiastic about what you do, you feel this positive energy. It’s very simple.\"");

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        index = randomQuote.Next(quotes.Count);
    }
    _quote = quotes.Values.ElementAt(index).ToString();
    _quotee = quotes.Keys.ElementAt(index).ToString();
    return (_quote, _quotee).ToString();
}
```

My WPF:

```cs
namespace DailyQuotes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
    
            DailyQuote daily = new DailyQuote();
            txtQuotee.Text = daily.Quoteee;
            txtPeriod.Text = daily.GetPeriod(); 
            txtQuote.Text = daily.DisplayQuote();
            txtTime.Text = daily.Time.ToString("h:mm tt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't tie the random selection to `DisplayQuote()` - do that in the `DailyQuote` constructor or in a separate `ShuffleQuote()` method or similar instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just return the tuple instead of calling `ToString` on it?

```cs
public static (string quote, string quotee) DisplayQuote() 
{
    ....
    return (_quote, _quotee);
}
```

Then you can access the two returns like this:

```cs
DailyQuote daily = new DailyQuote();
txtQuotee.Text = daily.quoeee;
txtQuote.Text = daily.quote;
```

This requires named [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), which are available from C# 7.0 and onwards. If you don't have C# 7.0 you'll need to use unnamed Tuples like so;

```
public Tuple<string,string> DisplayQuote()
{
    ...
    return new Tuple<string,string>(_quote, _quotee);
}

var tuple = DisplayQuote();
txtQuotee.Text = tuple.Item1;
txtQuote.Text = tuple.Item2;
```

Comment: I get the class DailyQuotes does not contain  daily.quote() or daily.quotee

Comment: @Medy Should be `txtQuotee.Text = daily._quoeee; txtQuote.Text = daily._quote;`

Comment: It still says the same thing that is my private field I can access it through properties but they return my default value and I'm trying to a get the values from Dictionary in  the DisplayQuote method. Thank you guys though.

Comment: @Medy you need to adjust the function declaration and return of `DisplayQuote` to a tuple instead of a string. Then you will be able to access the returned tuple via name or `Item1`, `Item2` ect.